# Detecting ESP chip ID and MAC address through UART, but unable to flash / dump the code to detected chip

Tags: esp32, esp-idf, soc, flashing

I am trying to flash code to `ESP32-D0WD-V3` (revision 3) which is on custom board. I am able to get the Chip ID and MAC address of the device. But code is not flashing. I am getting the following error message:

```
esptool.py v3.1-dev
Serial port COM3
Connecting........__
Chip is ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: c4:dd:57:93:7f:64
Uploading stub...

A fatal error occurred: Invalid head of packet (0x65)
CMake Error at run_serial_tool.cmake:50 (message):
python C:/espidf/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/esptool.py --chip
esp32 failed.
```

Comment: Are you using a VM by chance? They are notoriously finicky when it comes to using USB to serial converters. I was getting a similar error all while I was trying to use a VM; finally gave up. I assume that you've done the appropriate board checkout to ensure that you're touching the reset pin while attempting the flash.

Comment: Thank you @matebende for you reply.  I am not using VM. I am trying flash the code by using ESP32 UART communication only. And I pressed boot pin and reset button and tried many combination to flash it. But not yet got the solution.